# Calculate a large amount without running out of memory

Tags: python, lua

I think this will be a pretty hard or even impossible question. I have some code here that is build around [my scenario describet here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866665/formula-of-selecting-random-elements-from-a-generated-pool-of-elements).

I took that python code and translated it into lua code but then I spottet an error I made.

If the code is used for a list of ~10 weigths it will work fine but in my case I have lists with up to 60 weights. the code generates an array with all possible bitstrings of length n. and with n = 60 this array would be 2^60 large and that is way to much.

Is there any way to calculate this without generation such a large array?
My final code will be in lua but if you know a solution in any other language it will be fine to, I can still translate it later.

python code:

```
from math import prod
def bitstrings(n) :
    """Return all possible bitstrings of length n"""
    if n == 0 :
        yield []
        return
    else :
        for b in [0,1] :
            for x in bitstrings(n-1) :
                yield [b] + x


def prob_selected(weights, num_selected = 5) :

    # P(n generated, including e)*P(e of n selected | n generated including e)
    # i.e. Sum_n (n generated, including e) * #num_selections / #generated
    # num_selected = how many will be drawn out of the hat (at most)

    n = len(weights)
    final_probability = [0] * n
    
    for bits in bitstrings(n) :
        num_generated = sum(bits)
        prob_generated = prod([w if b else (1-w) for (w,b) in zip(weights, bits)])
        
        for i in range(n) :
            if bits[i] :
                final_probability[i] += prob_generated * min(num_selected, num_generated) / num_generated
    return final_probability


print(prob_selected([1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1]))
```

lua code:

```
-- python sum()
table.reduce = function (list, fn) 
    local acc
    for k, v in ipairs(list) do
        if 1 == k then
            acc = v
        else
            acc = fn(acc, v)
        end 
    end 
    return acc 
end

local function generateBitstrings (global_arr, n, arr, i)
    if i == n then
        table.insert(global_arr, {table.unpack(arr)})
        return
    end
    
    arr[i] = 0
    generateBitstrings(global_arr, n, arr, i + 1)
    
    arr[i] = 1
    generateBitstrings(global_arr, n, arr, i + 1)
end

local function prob_selected (weights, num_selected)
    local n = #weights
    local final_probability = {}
    
    for i=1, n do
        final_probability[i] = 0
    end
    
    local globalArr = {}
    generateBitstrings(globalArr, n + 1, {}, 1)
    for ibots, bits in ipairs(globalArr) do 
        local num_generated = table.reduce(
            bits,
            function(a, b)
                return a + b
            end
        )

        local prob_generated = 1
        local bitsLength = #bits
        for i=1,bitsLength do
            if bits[i] == 1 then
                prob_generated = prob_generated * weights[i]
            else
                prob_generated = prob_generated * (1 - weights[i])
            end
        end
        
        for i=1,n do
            if bits[i] == 1 then
                final_probability[i] = final_probability[i] + (prob_generated * math.min(num_selected, num_generated) / num_generated)
            end
        end
    end
    return final_probability
end

print (table.concat (prob_selected({1, 1, 1, 1, 1,0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1}, 5), ', '))
```

Comment: without reading through your code: if you run out of memory you need more memory. if ths is not an option you need to move things from ram to harddisk. or if the calculations allow it you split them into steps that do not consume as much memory. this is a software design problem and hence off-topic here.

Comment: Is it correct that `generateBitstrings` returns bit strings with any number of fields equal to one, not only five such fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will save you from running out of memory, though not from anything else. It uses a recursively called iterator, implemented as a coroutine, to generate all possible binary arrays (**UPD**: I also made the same iterator return the number of non-zero array items):

```lua
local function bitStrings (size)
    return coroutine.wrap (function ()
        if size == 0 then
            coroutine.yield ({}, 0)
        else
            for bit_string, bits in bitStrings (size - 1) do
                bit_string [size] = 0
                coroutine.yield (bit_string, bits)
                bit_string [size] = 1
                coroutine.yield (bit_string, bits + 1)
            end
        end
    end)
end         
    
local start = os.clock()
local function prob_selected (weights, num_selected)
    local format, min, clock, print = string.format, math.min, os.clock, print
    
    local n = #weights
    local final_probability = {}
    local counter = 0
    local total = 2 ^ n
    local total_s = format ('%d', total)
    for bits, num_generated in bitStrings (n) do
        counter = counter + 1
        local percent = counter / total
        local now = clock()
        local left = (now - start) / percent * (1 - percent)
        print (format ('%d', counter) .. ' / ' .. total_s .. '(' .. format ('%.0f', percent * 100) .. ' %), ' .. format ('%.1f minutes', left / 60) .. ' left')
        local ratio = min (num_selected, num_generated) / num_generated

        local prob_generated = 1
        for i = 1, n do
            if bits[i] == 1 then
                prob_generated = prob_generated * weights[i]
            else
                prob_generated = prob_generated * (1 - weights[i])
            end
        end
        
        for i = 1, n do
            if bits[i] == 1 then
                final_probability[i] = (final_probability[i] or 0) + (prob_generated * ratio)
            end
        end
    end
    return final_probability
end

-- Test:
local size = 20
local probabilities = {}
for i = 1, size do
    probabilities [i] = math.random ()
end
local selection = 5
print ('Size', size, 'selection', selection)
print ('Probabilities', table.concat (probabilities, ', '))
print ('Probabilities to be selected into ' .. tostring (selection), table.concat (prob_selected(probabilities, selection), ', '))
print (string.format ('%.1f seconds', os.clock() - start))
```

Below is a variant, for Lua 5.3 with bitmaps represented by integers, but it is not any faster, and I am not sure it is reliable:

```lua
local function countBits (i)
    local counter = 0
    local shifted = i
    while (shifted ~= 0) do
        counter = counter + (shifted & 1)
        shifted = shifted >> 1
    end
    return counter
end

local function checkBit (bits, n)
    return (bits >> (n - 1)) & 1
end

local start = os.clock()
local function prob_selected (weights, num_selected)
    local format, min, clock, print = string.format, math.min, os.clock, print

    local n = #weights
    local final_probability = {}
    local counter = 0
    local total = 2 ^ n
    local total_s = string.format ('%d', total)
    for bits = 0, total - 1 do
        counter = counter + 1
        local percent = counter / total
        local now = clock()
        local left = (now - start) / percent * (1 - percent)
        print (format ('%d', counter) .. ' / ' .. total_s .. '(' .. format ('%.0f', percent * 100) .. ' %), ' .. format ('%.1f minutes', left / 60) .. ' left')
        local num_generated = countBits (bits)
        local ratio = min (num_selected, num_generated) / num_generated     
        local prob_generated = 1
        for i = 1, n do     
            if checkBit (bits, i) == 1 then
                prob_generated = prob_generated * weights[i]
            else
                prob_generated = prob_generated * (1 - weights[i])
            end
        end
        
        for i = 1, n do
            if checkBit (bits, i) == 1 then
                final_probability[i] = (final_probability[i] or 0) + (prob_generated * ratio)
            end
        end
    end
    return final_probability
end

-- Test:
local size = 25
local probabilities = {}
for i = 1, size do
    probabilities [i] = math.random ()
end
local selection = 5
print ('Size', size, 'selection', selection)
print ('Probabilities', table.concat (probabilities, ', '))
print ('Probabilities to be selected into ' .. tostring (selection), table.concat (prob_selected(probabilities, selection), ', '))
print (string.format ('%.1f seconds', os.clock() - start))
```

And this is a combination of the above two approaches, faster than either:

```lua
local function bitMaps (size)
    return coroutine.wrap (function ()
        if size == 1 then
            coroutine.yield (0, 0)
        else
            for bit_string, bits in bitMaps (size - 1) do
                bit_string = bit_string << 1
                coroutine.yield (bit_string, bits)
                coroutine.yield (bit_string | 1, bits + 1)
            end
        end
    end)
end     

local function checkBit (bits, n)
    return (bits >> (n - 1)) & 1
end

local start = os.clock()
local function prob_selected (weights, num_selected)
    local format, min, clock, print = string.format, math.min, os.clock, print

    local n = #weights
    local final_probability = {}
    local counter = 0
    local total = 2 ^ n
    local total_s = string.format ('%d', total)
    for bits, num_generated in bitMaps (n) do
        counter = counter + 1
        local percent = counter / total
        local now = clock()
        local left = (now - start) / percent * (1 - percent)
        print (format ('%d', counter) .. ' / ' .. total_s .. '(' .. format ('%.0f', percent * 100) .. ' %), ' .. format ('%.1f minutes', left / 60) .. ' left')
        local ratio = min (num_selected, num_generated) / num_generated     
        local prob_generated = 1
        for i = 1, n do     
            if checkBit (bits, i) == 1 then
                prob_generated = prob_generated * weights[i]
            else
                prob_generated = prob_generated * (1 - weights[i])
            end
        end
        
        for i = 1, n do
            if checkBit (bits, i) == 1 then
                final_probability[i] = (final_probability[i] or 0) + (prob_generated * ratio)
            end
        end
    end
    return final_probability
end

-- Test:
local size = 25
local probabilities = {}
for i = 1, size do
    probabilities [i] = math.random ()
end
local selection = 5
print ('Size', size, 'selection', selection)
print ('Probabilities', table.concat (probabilities, ', '))
print ('Probabilities to be selected into ' .. tostring (selection), table.concat (prob_selected(probabilities, selection), ', '))
print (string.format ('%.1f seconds', os.clock() - start))
```